# Warnings converted to errors once build completes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019 I have a weird issue where warnings get converted to errors and double clicking them does nothing (rather than link me to the code with the problem.)

For context all these warnings are in an auto-generated .designer.cs file so manually fixing them would be pointless since they would be overwritten next time it is generated.

The only extension I have installed is ReSharper but that is only in VS 2017. Both 2015 and 2019 do not have it installed.

I've tried going through all the projects and ensuring that "Treat warnings as errors" was set to "None" (all projects were set that way to begin with, I didn't have to change any to None).
They all look like this:
[image]

I tried restarting my PC, closing VS and deleting the hidden .vs and .suo files (then restarting my PC again).

Most of the warnings are like so, where it uses the keyword "virtual" rather than "override". Furthermore as you can see on the second line it even calls the previous "error" a warning.

[image: warning as error]

Other members of my team see them as warnings only so clearly I have a local configuration problem but I don't see anything obviously related under Tools->Options.

There must be some setting I'm missing, I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: These look like *Code Analysis* Warnings - go to the according Project Setting tab and uncheck the *Enable Code Analysis on Build* option and/or the *Suppress results from generated code* option and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Any chance any of [these switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019) are in use somewhere?

Comment: @Filburt thanks for the suggestion. "Enable Code Analysis on Build" was already disabled. I turned off "Suppress results from generated code" in all projects, closed VS, deleted the .vs folder and then did a clean+rebuild of the project. Errors still persist

Comment: @JohnWu they are all set to W4. Which shouldn't affect warnings treated as errors. If I turn it to W1 the errors go away, but that also means I don't get the full analysis on the other files in that project which doesn't seem like a good solution.
I'm not sure how to check if the "WX" flag is set, but seeing as how the related setting is set to "None" I would assume it is off.

Comment: Uninstalling all versions of VS and reinstalling VS 2015 now treats them as warnings. I'm still having a potentially unrelated issue where it refuses to generate .pdb files though *shrugs

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my .Net standard project and use a Visual Studio 2019[16.9.2] with Resharper[2020.3.2] extension installed.
Even the "Enable Code Analysis on Build" is disabled, seems like a code analysis ruleset file still exists.

I fixed the issue doing following steps:

1. Open a RuleSet file from Solution Explorer.
2. In RuleSet window, select a problematic project
3. Untick any rules based on the warning number that get converted to error.
4. Save the file and build the project again.

[image]

**Updated**

Once the issue fixed, re-activate(tick) the rules and Enable code analysis again  to keep the code analysis working. there should be no warning converted to error.

Comment: This would skip the rule altogether. Looks like the "treat warnings as errors" setting might be corrupted. Did you try setting that value to "All", build, set it to "None" or "Specific Warnings" and build again?

Comment: i ticked the rules to replicate the issue before trying your suggestion but could not replicate the issue anymore.